# Path for saving files

Tags: python, path, save, pathlib

I'm trying to take files from  'D:\Study\Progs\test\samples' and after transforming .wav to .png I want to save it to 'D:\Study\Progs\test\"input value"' but after "name = os.path.abspath(file)" program takes a wrong path "D:\Study\Progs\test\file.wav" not "D:\Study\Progs\test\samples\file.wav". What can I do this it? [Here's my debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuzII.png) [And console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drB1T.png)

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


pa = "./"
save = pa+input()
os.mkdir(save)
for file in os.listdir("./samples"):
    if file.endswith(".wav"):
        print(file)
        name = os.path.abspath(file)
        ss = os.path.splitext(name)[0]+".png"
        print(name)
        audio = name
        x, sr = librosa.load(audio, mono=True, duration=5)
        save_path = os.path.join(save, ss)
        X = librosa.stft(x)
        Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
        plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
        librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr)
        plt.savefig(save_path)
```

Comment: To make it perfectly clear where you want to save the file, maybe edit the code in your question to print `save_path`, show us what comes out, and then show us what you want the full saved path and filename to be.

Comment: I added 2 pics of my output. Full saved path should be D:\Study\Progs\test\voice\bar.png

Comment: Look at the value of save and ss in your debug output.  I dont think you meant to join them.   Try not to mix the different ways of addressing the files and directories, eg keep them all absolute - or be clear what is a directory and what is a file, what is absolute and what is relative.  You might find the pathlib module easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `pathlib` as @Andrew suggests, I think what you're trying to do could be accomplished by using the current working directory and the stem of each .wav file to construct the filename for your .png.

```
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path.cwd()  # Current path.
sample_dir = cwd / "samples"  # Source files are here.

# Make some demo files if necessary.
if not sample_dir.exists():
    sample_dir.mkdir()
    (sample_dir / "file1.wav").touch()  # Make empty demo file.
    (sample_dir / "file2.wav").touch()  # Make empty demo file.

for file in sample_dir.glob("*.wav"):
    print(file)
    outfile = (cwd / file.stem).with_suffix(".png")
    print(f"->{outfile}")
    pass  # Replace this with whatever else needs to be done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my alternative working variant

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path.cwd()
print("Vvedite directoriu dlya sohraneniya resultatov:")
sf = input()
save_folder = cwd / sf
print("Vvedite nazvanie directorii s primerami .wav failov:")
smpl = input()
sample_dir = cwd / smpl
os.mkdir(save_folder)

for file in sample_dir.glob("*.wav"):
    print(file)
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    outfile = os.path.splitext(base)[0] + ".png"
    print(f"->{outfile}")
    audio = file
    x, sr = librosa.load(audio, mono=True, duration=5)
    save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, outfile)
    X = librosa.stft(x)
    Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr)
    plt.savefig(save_path)
```